# pivotear un dataframe por una columna

Tags: python, pivot

tengo un dataframe con datos de personas con la siguiente estructura:

| orden | col2 | tipodni | mesa | mesa-orden |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PABLO | DNI-EA | 1 | 1_1 |
| 1 | CORZ466 | DNI-EA | 1 | 1_1 |
| 1 | 111222333 | DNI-EA | 1 | 1_1 |
| 2 | PEDRO | DNI-EC | 1 | 1_2 |
| 2 | SVS343 | DNI-EC | 1 | 1_2 |
| 2 | 222333444 | DNI-EC | 1 | 1_2 |

donde los datos de una persona están distribuidos en bloques de 3 filas, las columnas orden, tipodni, mesa y mesa-orden repiten los valores en cada bloque, y la unica que cambia es la columna col2 que tiene en la primer fila el nombre de la persona, en la segunda la direccion y en la tercera el numero de dni. A su vez orden tipodni y mesa son columnas que tienen valores que pueden repetirse entre personas pero mesa-orden es un valor exacto y unico de la persona.

deseo pivotear sobre la columna mesa-orden que es la única que posee valores únicos por cada persona y obtener los valores de la columna col2 separandolos en columnas NOMBRE DIRECCION y DNI
El df debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

| orden | NOMBRE | DIRECCION | DNI | tipodni | mesa | mesa-orden |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PABLO | CORZ 446 | 111222333 | DNI-EA | 1 | 1_1 |
| 1 | PEDRO | SVS343 | 222333444 | DNI-EC | 1 | 1_2 |

No estoy pudiendo lograrlo, alguien podría indicarme como hacerlo?

Comment: Por favor adjunta bien qué es lo que quieres lograr, esto es sencillo con pandas.

Comment: Ahi lo edite había escrito mal y quedaba desordenado

Comment: Según lo que veo, no son valores únicos, y otra, cuál es la diferencia entre tu tabla de arriba y la de abajo? Veo que son exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: la tabla de arriba tiene en la columna col2 la informacion de nombre apellido y dni en bloques de 3 filas, por ende la columna que hay que usar para pivotear es la de mesa-orden que tiene valores unicos por cada bloque de 3 filas, por lo tanto el resultado debería quedar como en la tabla de abajo en donde en lugar de 6 filas hay 2 y los valores de la columna 2 estan pivoteados en 3 columnas nombre direccion y dni

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el código que has intentado utilizar así como el resultado deseado.

Comment: ya lo logre comento como lo hice seguramente no es la mejor opcion pero es la que me funcionó dado que el df estaba muy sucio por ello no andaba un simple pivot. Primero tube que eliminar

Comment: Que bien que resolviste tu propia pregunta. Redacta una respuesta, en dos días podrás aceptar tu solución.